# Multiple series highstock live chart not showing properly

Tags: charts, real-time, highcharts

I already have a static chart working with PHP and mysql, but this live chart wont show what's expected.

[image]

This is my chart code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'S1',
            data: []},{
            name: 'S2',
            data: []},{
            name: 'S3',
            data: []},{
            name: 'S4',
            data: []},{
            name: 'S5',
            data: []},{
            name: 'S6',
            data: []
        }]
    });        
});
```

This is the ajax code

```
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'live-server-data.php',
    success: function(points) {
        var series = chart.series,
            shift;
        $.each(series, function(i, s) {
            shift = s.data.length > 20;
            s.addPoint(points[i], false, shift);
        });
        setTimeout(requestData, 1000);   
        chart.redraw(); 
    },
    cache: false
    });
}
```

And finally this is an example of the JSON provided by live-server-data.php

```
[[1453945513000,640],[1453945513000,1197],[1453945513000,1112],[1453945513000,402],[1453945513000,879],[1453945513000,658]]
```

EDIT:

This is the code inside live-server-data.php

```
header("Content-type: text/json");
$x = time() * 1000;
for($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
    $ret[]=array($x, mt_rand(350, 1200));
}
echo json_encode($ret);
```

Comment: Sort your data ascending (by x-values). Most probably in your JS console you can see error from Highcharts library.

Comment: My data is provided sorted since it s randomly generated with current timestamp. [Here's a screenshot of chrome console](http://s24.postimg.org/oca86l1h1/Console.png).

Comment: Hmm.. That is strange - is there any chance to setup demo? For example using jsFiddle: since data is random anyway. I think there may be problem with `shift` param - you are shifting points which don't exist yet (redraw flag is set to false). Have you tried to remove "shift" param or set it always to false?

Comment: Tried to remove the shift param and set it always to false and it's the same. I noticed that when i add data with addPoint and redraw param is set to true [plots one second and then it freezes](https://i.gyazo.com/2597ec4c22939e475ae95acf3d824a10.gif) (stop retrieving new data). When it's set to false [It doesn't retrieve data at all but X axis behaves as it did.](https://i.gyazo.com/62bd45169d7f0cc3c3c92a50e554358b.gif)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with updating navigator series. When you go over all series:

```
 $.each(series, function(i, s) { ... });
```

Then you also update the navigator series. However, your AJAX data doesn't have enough points. I suggest to add one more point (e.g. the same as the first one in the data) to the AJAX response, and create separate series for navigator:

```
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: requestData
    }
  },

  navigator: {
    series: {
        data: []
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    data: []
   }, {
    name: 'Random data 2',
    data: []
  }]
});
```

And live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dqkjrd7k/1/